# Emojis really slow to render in browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, emoji

I'm trying to render a bunch of emojis as part of an emoji selector, but the browser is really slow at rendering them and usually hangs for several hundreds of milliseconds.

```js
const emojis = "‍‍⬛" + 
"" + 
"️‍❄️‍"

const body = document.querySelector('body');

for (const emoji of Array.from(emojis)) {
  const child = document.createElement('div');
  child.innerHTML = emoji;
  body.appendChild(child)
}
```

I tried on different browser and the all show similar behaviour. I attached a screenshot of the Firefox profiler.

[image: Profiler]

Answer (score 1):

Rendering a large number of emojis in the DOM can indeed cause performance issues due to the rendering complexity of each emoji. One possible optimization could be to use a single DOM element for rendering multiple emojis at once.

```
   const emojis = "‍‍⬛" + 
  "" + 
  "️‍❄️‍";

const emojisContainer = document.createElement('div');
emojisContainer.textContent = emojis;
document.body.appendChild(emojisContainer);
```

This approach involves creating a single div element and setting its textContent property to the entire string of emojis. This should perform better than creating individual elements for each emoji.

Or did you want the icons to have a selector for selection in chat?

Comment: Thanks, but as you say I'd like the user to be able to click on an icon at have that appear somewhere else

Comment: You could try read doc. about "DocumentFragment". Mby it will help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment